# Ajax response not calling success:function() when using jQuery 1.8.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ajax response not calling `success:function()` when using jQuery 1.8.3 but the code is working perfectly with jQuery 1.4.2.

Here the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#usn").on('keyup',function() {
        var dat=$("#usn").val();
        if($.trim(dat).length<10){
            $("#result").html("");
            $("#info").show();
        } else if($.trim(dat).length==10) {    
            txt=$("#usn").val();
            txt=txt.toUpperCase();
            var exp = /^[1-9][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/;
            if(exp.test(txt)){
                var resultType =$("input[name='resultType']:checked").val();
                $("#result").html("<img src=\"./result/loader.gif\"/><br/>Loading...");     
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "result/result_html.php?usn="+txt+"&resultType="+resultType,
                    dataType:"JSON",
                    success:function(result){
                        $("#info").hide();
                        $("#result").html(result);              
                        $("#usn").attr("placeholder", "USN"); 
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $("#result").html("Please enter a valid USN.");    
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The console is not showing any error. I can see in the console Ajax request is successfully completed. I can see the expected Ajax response in my script console.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Is the status code from the AJAX request HTTP 200?

Comment: Is the response valid JSON? http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @vondruska no it is HTML response

Comment: Then tell what should I use instead of dataType:"JSON",

Comment: @VishalVijay: Then why did you specify `dataType: 'JSON'` !?!? Use `dataType: 'html'`.

Comment: @VishalVijay "html" should work if it is a HTML response

Comment: @vondruska Yes that it

Comment: It is working with html...

Comment: Post it as answer please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within your `$.ajax()` call, the `dataType` is JSON. You said the the response was HTML in your comments. Simply changing the `dataType` to "html" should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As your sending response as `html`...the datatype should be `html` which in your case is `json`.. correcting that should work

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "result/result_html.php?usn="+txt+"&resultType="+resultType,
            dataType:"html",  //<-- here
            success:function(result){
                    $("#info").hide();
                    $("#result").html(result);              
                    $("#usn").attr("placeholder", "USN"); 
                }
        }).....
```