# Unable to get the response from an ajax call in the success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

After refering this stack link [Ajax response not calling success:function() when using jQuery 1.8.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177972/ajax-response-not-calling-successfunction-when-using-jquery-1-8-3I) am wondering why if I uncomment the datatype line the success function is not invoked.I can understand that dataType =JSON is not calling success function.Could some one help me out ?

```
function doAjaxCall(methodType,Url,params,requestType,callBackFunction)
{
    if(validate.variable(Url) && validate.variable(params))
    {
        $.ajax({
             type       :   methodType,
             url        :   Url,
//           dataType   :   'JSON', //if i uncomment i am not getting the response under     success
             data       :   params,
             success    :   function(data)
             {
                console.log(data);
                    callBackFunction(data);
             }
     });
}
}

function callBackFunctiontest(data)
{
    console.log('callBackFunctiontest : ' +data);

 }
doAjaxCall('GET','/getData?accountNumber=9840100672&oid=d11c9f66-4c55-4855-a99e-580ba8ef8d61','noparams','application/JSON',callBackFunctiontest);
```

Comment: the data will be retrieved as json object.....

Comment: I can understand that but i am not sure why it is not visiting the success function.

Comment: check ur console for any error

Comment: No errors i get one stmt like undefined.

Comment: why do you want to comment `dataType   :   'JSON'`?

Comment: can you remove question mark from end callback=? and send 'noparams=somevalue'

Comment: it's because data object is undefined........ that ur returning is not a valid json data

Comment: nope by default it will be application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 0):

If it's not passing in success function, put an error function. This way you'll be able to see the error and understand what's going on.

You can also open the developer console and have a look at the 'network' panel.

Comment: I checked in Network panel nothing strange status=ok. code=200 able to see the response.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're calling `callBackFunctiontest` which should then be calling `doAjaxCall`.

You're trying to use `data` when there is no variable named `data` in scope. It will throw an undefined exception and `doAjaxCall` will not get executed. So your AJAX request will never get sent.

Try getting rid of the `console.log('callBackFunctionTest : ' +data);`, or pass it a value for `data`.

Comment: That seems to work fine for me now. I removed the validation check so I could test it in JSFiddle - not sure if that's made any difference. You can try it here http://jsfiddle.net/fsf5v/1/.

Comment: it is not working for me when i tried using the link posted by you.

Comment: How strange. What browser are you using? In my console output I get `callBackFunctionTest : [object Object]` - which would indicate everything is working fine.

Comment: Ah Chrome itself i am not getting until i comment the datatype.

Comment: Nothing even appearing when running the code in JSFiddle? Works fine in Chrome for me (http://imgur.com/m5TFevI).

Answer (score 0):

I am using Express JS web framework and NodeJS, both latest versions -  4.x.x.

**Issue #1** - Not all of my POST ajax calls were being sent to my NodeJS server code.
How I found this is by trying to POST using Postman. All POSTMAN call requests were received by the server code but not the Express client requests. I checked by printing the console.log server debug statements to compare the findings between POSTMAN & Express Client.

**Issue #2** - I was never receiving any response message from the server even though the server responded with a status 200 OK.
For both the issues, I made a few changes, which I believe will help others.

1. In the ajax call, I added e.preventDefault(); where 'e' is the event which is triggered via #click/#onclick.
2. Within ajax function call, I added the parameter dataType: 'json'.
3. In the NodeJS server code, index.js, I replaced res.send(req.body.search_data); with res.json(req.body.search_data);
   P.S. - e.preventDefault() was actually built for a different purpose but **it helped because it prevents a link from following the URL which is what solved the above issues.**